# SharePoint Online Search shows results from old SP2013

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

We tested hybrid search on SPO and decided against it.
The test farm where it was set is not active anymore but search is still returning results from it.
How can I set the SPO search to show only results from the SPO tenant?
When I tried "remove search results" it did not find the URL

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **IsExternalContent** managed property in the SharePoint, and this property is set to true for all on-premises content. So you can limit search results to show only M365 content with `NOT IsExternalContent:true` .

Also, you could create a new result souce and change the default query transform to "`{?{searchTerms} NOT IsExternalContent:true}`". Then use this result for your search

Comment: I did that but the property "SPSiteURL" still shows URLs from the old test and production 2013. I also noticed that `slot item @root.slots.Path` points to the current URL. Am I doing something wrong?